# Push axios requests to axios.all array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Good night.

I'm trying to add a array to `axios.all([])` array!

My code:

> app2.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#central',
    data: {
        estilo: 'resize:none;text-align:center;color:red;width:450px;height:200px;font-size:15px;',
        capkey: 'text-align:center;color:RED;font-size:17px;;width:20%;height:40%;',
        ativar: true,
        buttonvalue: 'Inserir lista',
        livestyle: 'color:#519872;font-size:17px;',
        diestyle: 'color:#fd2eb3;font-size:17px',
        lives: [],
        dies: [],
        testar: axios.all([])
    },
    methods: {

        checkin(e) {
            console.log(this)
            this.buttonvalue = 'Testar'
            this.ativar = false
            var lista = e.split('\n');

            lista.map((value, key) => {

                this.testar.push(axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php', {
                    crossDomain: true,
                    params: {
                        lista: value
                    }
                }));


            });

            this.testar.then(responseArr => {
                //code...
            });


        },
    }
})
```

How to add requests (object) to `axios.all ([])` using the push for arrays and then process them all in parallel ?

```
vue.js:1897 TypeError: this.testar.push is not a function
    at app2.js:24
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.all([])` will return a promise. So using `.push` on a promise will give you the error:

> TypeError: this.testar.push is not a function

Instead just create an array without the axios function.

```
data: {
    ...
    testar: []
},
```

Inside the `checkin` function change the `map` logic to the following rules. This will create a new array with promises and assigns the new array to the `this.testar` property. Then with `Promise.all` you can wait for all the promises to resolve in parallel.

```
var lista = e.split('\n');
this.testar = lista.map((value) =>

    axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php', {
        crossDomain: true,
        params: {
            lista: value
        }
    });

);

Promise.all(this.testar).then(responseArr => {
    //code...
});
```

If you don't want to wait for all the Promises to end before continuing you could remove the `Promise.all` function and add your `then` methods to the `axios.get` function.

```
var lista = e.split('\n');
this.testar = lista.map((value) =>

    axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php', {
        crossDomain: true,
        params: {
            lista: value
        }
    }).then(response => {
       // code...
    });

);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! But how can I prevent promise.all from waiting for all requests to be completed before returning the answer? I wanted that for each response of any request, the server already brought the response of that request

Comment: Remove `Promise.all` and add the `then` logic to the `axios.get` function. This way every `axios.get` call got it's own way to proceed with `then` and won't wait for each promise to resolve.

Comment: But is it basically the same thing? Wouldn't the requests still wait for the others to be completed before returning the answer?

Comment: ```axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php', {
                    crossDomain: true,
                    params: {
                        lista: value
                    }
                }).then(responseArr => {

                    console.log(responseArr)
    
            })```

Comment: No, the promises will run separately. They will not wait for each other. But if you would like to do something whenever **all** promises are finished, then `Promise.all` comes into play. They still run separately, but values of all promises are collected in an array and returned into a single promise when they finish.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
new Vue({
el: '#central',
data: {
    estilo: 'resize:none;text-align:center;color:red;width:450px;height:200px;font-size:15px;',
    capkey: 'text-align:center;color:RED;font-size:17px;;width:20%;height:40%;',
    ativar: true,
    buttonvalue: 'Inserir lista',
    livestyle: 'color:#519872;font-size:17px;',
    diestyle: 'color:#fd2eb3;font-size:17px',
    lives: [],
    dies: [],
    testar: []
},
methods: {

    checkin(e) {
        console.log(this)
        this.buttonvalue = 'Testar'
        this.ativar = false
        var lista = e.split('\n');

        lista.map((value, key) => {

            this.testar.push(axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php', {
                crossDomain: true,
                params: {
                    lista: value
                }
            }));


        });

        axios.all(this.testar).then(axios.spread(...responseArr) => {
            //code... var x= responseArr[0]
        });


    },
}
```

})